# How could I create a linked list of all objects that were ever created with that class?

Tags: c++, list, class, methods

**Hello**

I have class A, and that class has constructors, mutator methods, inspector methods and so on. How could I create a linked list of all objects that were ever created with that class (by all objects I mean that a "new" object should also be linked as a new one if it is changed by the mutator method). If possible with a small example.

Comment: Make the list a `static` member of the class, then append `this` to it in your class' constructors.

Comment: And don't forget to remove `this` from the list in the destructor.

Comment: Please don't do this. I am certain this will be a bad idea.

Comment: How strong of a requirement is "ever"? Do you also want to know about every temporary object that was created? Are you trying to find a memory leak? I would recommend you rethink your approach to the problem you're really trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use a static list, and modify it from the constructor and destructor. For example:

```
class A {
    static std::list<A *> s_instances;

public:
    A() { A::s_instances.push_back(this); }

    ~A() { A::s_instances.remove(this); }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what Sid S meant:

**A.h**

```
class A {
public:
    A(vector<A*>& a_objects_vector) {
        a_objects_vector.push_back(this);
    }
    ~A(vector<A*>& a_objects_vector) {
        a_objects_vector.remove(this);
    }
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "A.h"

int main() {
    vector<A*> all_a_objects;
    A a(all_a_objects), *a1 = new A(all_a_objects);
    /*Do your magic here...*/
    delete a1;
    return 0;
}
```